# how do I delete image file less than particular size?

Tags: php

I want delete files less than a particular size say 10kb. how do I do it in PHP??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like so, for example:

```
foreach (glob('/path/to/files/*') as $file) {
    if (is_writable($file) && filesize($file) < (1024 * 10)) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

Comment: yup, file_exists was redundant here :)

Answer (score 0):

To check size of file you need use [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php). 
Here you got how [list files in directory](http://www.laughing-buddha.net/php/lib/dirlist). Here you got [documentation of readdir.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php)

Using those links should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might help:

```
<?php
  // outputs e.g.  somefile.txt: 1024 bytes

  $filename = 'somefile.txt';
  if(filesize($filename) == (10*1024)){
     unlink($filename);
  }
?>
```